# Understanding Constr type of Data.Data package of Haskell

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

I am trying to understand the Constr type of Data.Data package. Consider the session below. `dataTypeConstrs` returns a list of `Constr`, both zero- and one-argument constructors of Maybe. Attempting to re-create the list fails due to obvious type error. Is it a special behavior of GHC regarding to Constr value?

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XScopedTypeVariables
Prelude> :module +Data.Data
Prelude Data.Data> dataTypeConstrs (dataTypeOf (Nothing :: Maybe ()))
[Nothing,Just]
Prelude Data.Data> :i it
it :: [Constr]  -- Defined at <interactive>:4:1

Prelude Data.Data> let i2 :: [Constr] = [Nothing,Just]

<interactive>:6:23:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Constr’ with actual type ‘Maybe a0’
    In the expression: Nothing
    In the expression: [Nothing, Just]
```

Comment: Interesting question. In looking at Data.Data I see there are functions for create Constr instances. Like mkConstr. I'm guessing that the instance of Show for Constr doesn't give you enough detail to actually construct a Constr as you are attempting with i2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a list of actual constructors, but a list of *constructor representations*. Its `Show` instance uses a fast and loose output which makes it seem something else.

Just pretend it's something as

```
[ Constr{ name = "Nothing", args = 0, ... }
, Constr{ name = "Just", args = 1, ... }
]
```

except it's being displayed in a loose way.

More precisely, that is the *internal*, opaque constructor representation. Use the `constr*` observer to inspect a value of type `Constr`.

Comment: Indeed, I've missed the Show instance for Constr `instance Show Constr where show = constring` which shows the name of a constructor.  Just a good old poor Show design problem, Thanks!